# How to count the href

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I count the `href` attributes of my HTML?

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="8">
                <a href="111">2</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="112">3</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="114">4</a>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any efforts from your side, you should post what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean "count the href"? Show code you've tried already

Comment: int find = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href*='table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]']")).Count;

Comment: Do you want to get number of links with `href` attribute?

Comment: i just want to count how many href in td in specific td

Comment: How many `href`?! Clarify what exactly you mean as `href` is an attribute of link and there should be just one `href` attribute in `a` element and none in `td`

Comment: ok sry, i saw above the code, there are 3 a element. so i just count the number 3..

Comment: try `int find = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table tr>td>a[href]")).Count;`

Answer (score 0):

Get the elements by tagname and het the size of the result:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href]")).size()
```

Comment: OP added tag `C#` to get solution in appropriate programming language. Your solution is in `Java`

Comment: Also note that `href` is not a tag and this code will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I generally avoid XPath, this seems like the time to use it.

If you are simply trying to get the number of links on a page without having to filter on specific links, you can do this in C# by:

```
int linkCount = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a")).Count;
```

You can then `Assert` on that number returned (to actually do a test on this, if you don't assert, the test will always pass). If you want to filter on specific links I would use something other than XPath.

Comment: Why you think that it's a right case to use `XPath`- more reasonable to use search by `TagName`... Also check OP comments- he definitely doesn't want to get *all* links from page

Comment: In this example I would use XPath due to the generic nature of the requirement, however I do agree with you that TagName would also be a good way to search for all links. I have looked at the comments and I disagree with you on the point that he definitely doesn't want to get all links from the page. I think this is more the ambiguity of the question and comments rather than anything else.